# the following print tree function does not work why?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, c++14, binary-tree

the code of my print function is -

```
void print(node* root){
    cout<<root->data<<" ";
    print(root->left);
    print(root->right);
    return;
}
```

where the structure of node used is:-

```
struct node
{
int data;
node* left;
node* right;
};
```

I can't figure out what the problem is.Is there any problem in the logic of the code?

Comment: There are several problems that will prevent this code from compiling. In the print() function it should be print(struct *node). When printing the node you will also (probably) want to print the node->data element as well. And then you will need a main() function entry point to actually execute your code.

Comment: Before we can help you fix a problem, you have to tell us what the problem is. Does the code not compile? Does fail to run? Does is start to run, but crash? Is any error message displayed? Have you run it under the debugger? If you don't know how to use a debugger, now is the time to learn. Just dropping some code and saying, "it doesn't work" is not making it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive function is pretty close to working, but it is missing a base case, i.e. it does not tell the compiler what to do when `root` is `nullptr`. Adding an instruction to exit when `root` is `nullptr` will fix the problem:

```
void print(node* root) {
    if (!root) return;
    ... // The remaining code should remain the same
}
```

**Note:** the `return` statement at the bottom of a `void` function serves no particular purpose, and should be removed.

Comment: oh yeah thanks a lot i totally forgot such a stupid thing.